# Easy manipulation of transparency in BGE

Tags: game-engine, transparency

I'm making a video game from concept to finished piace (still a  big noob) where there's this holographic screen. I want to be able  to manipulate it as easy as I do it in cycles. It doesn't have to  be by using nodes, but once I have it one way in the game engine I don't want to recreate the hole screen  just because the text is too small, or too transparent. In cycles  I have control over everything. Here's an example - 
[image]
Nodes - http://www.pasteall.org/pic/91298

The text is too big? - No problem, here's the mapping node. The  blur is too pronounced? - Here's the slider of the Mix Shader. I can also overlay other images or another text the same way the blur is on the screen and the text on the blur.

To what extend can I do all of this in the GE? as I  said, it doesn't has to be with nodes. Easy manipulation is the  problem.

Update: If alpha textures are the only way to go, Is it possible to control each element on the screen as a separate alpha texture. For example - if the text is too pronounced, I can make it more transparent, without effecting anything else. Is that possible?

Comment: transparency can be done with other Alpha-Sort/Blend or Add. Rendering a whole screen can be done via VideoTexture. But I do not know about filtering (blur) the output.

Comment: @Monster Thanks for the comment. The blur is just another image (blured in Compositor and saved as separate image). Is it possible to control the transparency of the alpha textures (make the text more transparent for example)? Which means every element on the screen can be separately controlled. Is that possible?

Comment: It depends. Videotexture is a bit tricky as it overrides the material options.I need some further tests to find out what is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an interesting workarround - If you save a very low rez. image with part color and part transparency you can adjust the transparency by moving the texture - 
[image]
[image]

Maybe will work for some cases because there is a transition between the color and the alpha which means there is no even distribution of color and transparency over the plane.

Comment: In "blender game" on Material/Game settings/Alpha blend only the the "Add" option workls and it's too bright. Is this the only solution? How to fix it?
http://www.pasteall.org/pic/91347